# how to use data of useParams in createContext hook in functional component react js

Tags: reactjs, react-context

i want to pass data of useParams() inside the createContext() so that i can use data  in different components

login component:-

```
import React,{createContext} from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

export const Context = createContext(companyName);

function Login(){
const {companyName} =  useParams();  
return(
    <div>//somedata//<div?    
)
} 

export default Login
```

Note:- in companyName i have data `{name = "hee"}`

another component:-

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react';
import { Context } from './Login';
 function Component(){
const aa = useContext(Context)
  console.log("context",aa)
}
```

in this component i get context undefined

i try this also

```
   import React,{createContext} from 'react';
    import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
    
    export const Context = createContext();
    
    function Login(){
    const {companyName} =  useParams();  
    return(
      <Context.Provider value={companyName}>
        <StateMaster/>
      </Context.Provider>

        <div>//somedata//<div?    
    )
    } 
    
    export default Login
```

this time app crashed, login component not working (render), i just want to pass data of useParams into createContext. please help to accomplish this

Comment: Please try adding `Context.Provider` inside your `App.js` instead of inside your `Login`-Component. The Provider has to be wrapped around your component tree. You can also check https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-for-beginners/#how-do-i-use-react-context  for a working example.

Comment: What is the point of duplicating the params value in another context from the context the router is providing? What's the point of shifting from `const { companyName } = useParams();` in consumers to `const aa = useContext(Context);`? There doesn't appear to be any benefit here at all.

Answer (score 0):

The context is probably not working because the provider is not farther up the component tree than the consumer, but it's hard to tell for sure without seeing how the components are arranged.

In any event, I think context is not necessary here. If you're just using the context to provide a value that's available via a hook, then i recommend you use a hook instead of context. Either the child can directly call useParams:

```
function Component() {
  const aa = useParams().companyName;
}
```

Or if you can extract the logic to a custom hook:

```
function useCompanyName() {
  return useParams().companyName;
}

function Component() {
  const aa = useCompanyName();
}
```